# Is there a difference between articles and determiners?

Tags: terminology, articles, determiners

I have heard *the*, *a*, and *an* referred to as both articles and determiners. Do these two terms mean the same thing, or are there some differences between them? Can a word be an article but not a determiner, and vice versa?

Comment: If you accept the word class determiner/determinative, as most modern linguists do, a quick look at Wikipedia articles (other sense) shows that the articles form a subclass of determiners.

Comment: @Edwin: Even without getting too bogged down in "professional" terminology, most of us probably know that *the/a* are the *definite/indefinite **articles***. And ordinary semantics suggests to me that *this/that/those/these* (which aren't "traditional" articles) ***determine which particular one we're talking about***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wouldn't common sense also tell us that that's the function of *the* ans *a* too?

Comment: Well, *this/that/those/these* also do double duty as demonstrative pronouns and can therefore standalone. Their physically demonstrative aspect sets them apart from *the/an/a*, which must precede a noun to function within a sentence. The two groups provide/indicate different types of information.

Comment: @miltonaut Yes, people like me who don't believe in determiners would agree. But the words you've highlighted are pronouns in nearly all grammars - not determiners ... Big hole in the grammar, imo :)

Comment: _this_ is a pronoun when it's used by itself, e.g. _this is the place_. It's a determiner when it's used to qualify a noun, e.g. _this car is red_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In grammar *[determiner](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/determiner#determiner__5)* is the more general category:

> 2. Grammar A modifying word that determines the kind of reference a
>      noun or noun group has, for example a, the, every. See also *[article](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/article)*.
>
> *ODO*

Wikipedia lists seven common [types of determiners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner#Types_of_determiners):

> - Articles
> - Demonstratives
> - Possessives
> - Quantifiers
> - Numerals
> - Distributives
> - Interrogatives

An *article* is one type of *determiner*.

> *[definite article](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/definite-article)*
>   noun
>   Grammar A determiner (the in English) that introduces a noun phrase and implies that the thing mentioned has
>   already been mentioned, or is common knowledge, or is about to be
>   defined (as in *the book on the table*; *the art of government*; *the
>   famous public school in Berkshire*).
>   Compare with
>
> *[indefinite article](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/indefinite-article)*
>   noun
>   Grammar A determiner (a and an in English) that introduces a noun
>   phrase and implies that the thing referred to is non-specific (as in
>   *she bought me a book*; *government is an art*; *he went to a public
>   school*).
>   Typically, the indefinite article is used to introduce new
>   concepts into a discourse.
>
> *ODO*

In grammar, not all *determiners* are *articles*, but all *articles* are *determiners*.